# Can I stay in Europe after I complete my studies as long as my visa is still valid?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, study, schengen-visas

I (U.S. citizen) studied abroad in France from August 2017 to May 2018, but the visa issued to me -- Type D, multi-entry -- is for the entire year (e.g. August to August).

My understanding, then, is that I can stay, even if my study program is over since my visa/residence permit doesn't expire until August 2018.

Is that correct?

Comment: You should ask this question on expatriates because you are holding a long term visa so it's not on topic here